# Scaling Object turns the textures white (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure out why my Object's textures keep turning white once I scale the object down to 1% (or less) of its normal size.

I can manipulate the objects realtime with my fingers and there is a threshold where all the textures (except a few) turn completely ghost white, as shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ18i.jpg

Any input to fix is appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52994331/edit) your question and include more information about the asset you are displaying as well as the code/libraries you are using to resize and display it.

Comment: You would also normally upload screenshots and images here to stackoverflow (can be done in the editor directly). If the external link goes dead, the quality of the question will most likely deteriorate.

Comment: hi mike, welcome to SO. i have seen this problem before, though i dont think your question is a duplicate per se,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential cause of this issue is due to how certain shaders can miscalculate how to render textures when scales are set to low values.

To be able to render this asset so small using the same shader, re-import the mesh with a smaller scale factor (in the mesh import settings), and that may fix it.

Comment: This was the fix, my default scale factor was at 1 - putting it to .1 appears to allow me to make it 10x smaller before it turns white! Thank you!!!

Comment: Thanks! Please upvote and/or accept this answer so that future visitors with similar questions can find it more easily.

Comment: It says since I'm unable to because I have less than 15 reputation points :(. Anyone reading this please upvote Ruzihm's answer since it resolved my issue

Comment: You should be able to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking on the grey checkmark below the score.

Answer (score 0):

select `ARCamera` then `camera`, in the inspector, select the cameras clipping plane and increase it(you want to find the minimum possible clipping that works to save on memory, so start at 20000, and work your way backwards til it stops working, then back up a notch).

next (still in the cameras inspector), select `Rendering Path` and set it to `Legacy Vertex Lit`

this should clear it up for you